# Changing Maps "detail/resolution" while still zooming in/out

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3, d3.js, bing-maps, geojson

I'm toying around with d3.js and some other javascript libraries plotting geoJSON data in the browser. I've done some cool things with the data, but to give it a bit more context I want to lay it over a map that fills the browser (i'll probably make it opaque to not distract). I've spent a few hours with the google and bing API, which have great "zoom" options, but **I want to specify how detailed the map becomes without further restricting how far I can zoom in**. Is there a way to do this? I.e. I want to zoom further in and be able to pan around, without all of the side streets appearing-- maintaining the "main drags" of the city I'm working with.

I'm open to using different resources, but this is not a commercial product so I don't want to pay anything. As far as I know, the option for increasing and decreasing the detail/resolution of the pane is by increasing or decreasing the zoom variable. Thanks.

Edit: There really doesn't need to be much interaction with the map. This is kind of the intention http://www.caudillweb.com/temp/d3_choropleth.html, but since it will be at the city level, as you can see when you zoom in that far all sorts of different elements and side streets appear, taking away from the clean view at a more zoomed-out level and it begins to distract from the data.

Comment: You would have to create separate GeoJSON files for the different details and load them as appropriate.

Comment: Have you looked into [Google Maps' Stylized Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?csw=1#map_features)?  You likely want to disable most of the map features.